# Using Existing Segmented Control to Control mkmapkit zoom

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I have a segmented control which controls the address and phone number as well as some other labels on a screen.

I am trying to also get this same control to zoom into the specific location of three locations on the mkmapview and make the zoom level at street view depending what button they push.  Any help would be appreciated.

### Here is my .m file:

```
    @implementation LocationInfoViewController;
@synthesize mapView;

-(void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setDelegate:self];

    MKCoordinateRegion morristown = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} };
    morristown.center.latitude = 40.797011;
    morristown.center.longitude = -74.482855;
    morristown.span.longitudeDelta = 0.60f;
    morristown.span.latitudeDelta = 0.60f;
    [mapView setRegion:morristown animated:YES];

    Annotation *ann1 = [[Annotation alloc] init];
    ann1.title = @"Sushi Lounge";
    ann1.subtitle = @"Morristown";
    ann1.coordinate = morristown.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation: ann1];

    MKCoordinateRegion hoboken = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} };
    hoboken.center.latitude = 40.738496;
    hoboken.center.longitude = -74.029434;
    hoboken.span.longitudeDelta = 0.60f;
    hoboken.span.latitudeDelta = 0.60f;
    [mapView setRegion:hoboken animated:YES];

    Annotation *ann2 = [[Annotation alloc] init];
    ann2.title = @"Sushi Lounge";
    ann2.subtitle = @"Hoboken";
    ann2.coordinate = hoboken.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann2];

    MKCoordinateRegion totawa = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} };
    totawa.center.latitude = 40.875682;
    totawa.center.longitude = -74.301787;
    totawa.span.longitudeDelta = 0.60f;
    totawa.span.latitudeDelta = 0.60f;
    [mapView setRegion:hoboken animated:YES];

    Annotation *ann3 = [[Annotation alloc] init];
    ann3.title = @"Sushi Lounge";
    ann3.subtitle = @"Totawa";
    ann3.coordinate = totawa.center;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann3];

}

-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation 

{
    MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
    MyPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

    UIButton *advertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [advertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    MyPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = advertButton;
    MyPin.draggable = NO;
    MyPin.highlighted = YES;
    MyPin.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    MyPin.canShowCallout = YES;

    return MyPin;
}

-(void)button:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button action");
}


    //Start of Segment control
-(IBAction) changeSegment:(id)sender


{
   //streetLabel--------------------------------------------- 
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        streetLabel.text = @"12 Schuyler Place";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        streetLabel.text = @"200 Hudson St.";
    }

    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        streetLabel.text = @"235 Route 46 West";
    }

    //phoneLabel---------------------------------------------

    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        phoneLabel.text = @"(973) 539-1135";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        phoneLabel.text = @"(201) 386-1117";
    }

    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        phoneLabel.text = @"(973) 890-0007";
    }
    //Monday----------------------------------------------
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        hoursLabel1.text = @"11:30am - 11:00pm";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        hoursLabel1.text = @"11:30pm - 11:30pm";
    }

    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        hoursLabel1.text = @"11:30am - 10:30pm";
    }
    //Tuesday------------------------------------------
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        hoursLabel2.text = @"11:30am - 11:00pm";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        hoursLabel2.text = @"11:30am - 11:30pm";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        hoursLabel2.text = @"11:30am -  10:30pm";
    }
    //Wednesday------------------------------------------
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        hoursLabel3.text = @"11:30am - 11:30pm";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        hoursLabel3.text = @"11:30am - 11:30pm";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        hoursLabel3.text = @"11:30am -  12:00am";
    }
    //Thursday------------------------------------------
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        hoursLabel4.text = @"11:30am - 12:00am";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        hoursLabel4.text = @"11:30am - 12:00pm";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        hoursLabel4.text = @"11:30am -  11:30pm";
    }
    //Friday------------------------------------------
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        hoursLabel5.text = @"11:30am - 12:00pm";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        hoursLabel5.text = @"11:30am - 1:00am";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        hoursLabel5.text = @"11:30am -  12:00am";
    }
    //Saturday------------------------------------------
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        hoursLabel6.text = @"12:00pm - 12:00am";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        hoursLabel6.text = @"12:00pm - 1:00am";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        hoursLabel6.text = @"12:00pm -  12:00am";
    }
    //Sunday------------------------------------------
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        hoursLabel7.text = @"12:00pm - 11:00pm";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        hoursLabel7.text = @"12:00pm - 11:30pm";
    }
    if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        hoursLabel7.text = @"12:00pm - 10:30pm";
    }
    if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        mapView.center.x == 40.738496;


    }
}





- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView

{

}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{

    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

*/

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

better just do more reading, here is a sample code you might want to study:

[MapCallouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746)

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to make the annotation variables `ann1`, `ann2`, and `ann3` ivars instead of local variables in `viewDidLoad`.

You will then be able to easily access them and change the map's coordinates in the `changeSegment:` method:

```
if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    //set streetLabel, phoneLabel, and hoursLabelX here also
    [mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(ann1.coordinate, 1000, 1000) animated:YES];
}
else 
if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    //set streetLabel, phoneLabel, and hoursLabelX here also
    [mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(ann2.coordinate, 1000, 1000) animated:YES];
}
else
if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
    //set streetLabel, phoneLabel, and hoursLabelX here also
    [mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(ann3.coordinate, 1000, 1000) animated:YES];
}
```

By the way, you can greatly simplify and shorten the code in `changeSegment:` by putting all the statements that apply to the same condition together as mentioned in the comments above instead of separately.